# Error in inheritence mapping in Entity framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, mapping

I have an existing database with this schema :

- Table User : UserID, FirstName, LastName
- Table Manager : ManagerID (PK, FK)
- Table Coordinator : CoordinatorID (PK, FK)

the FKs are referring to the UserID field in the table User

In the Entities side I have :

```
[Table("User")]
public abstract partial class User
{
  public int UserID { get; set; }
      public virtual string LastName{ get; set; }
  public virtual string Firstname{ get; set; }

    }

[Table("Manager")]
public partial class Manager : User
{
    public int ManagerID{ get; set; }
    }

[Table("Coordinator")]
public partial class Coordinator: User
{
    public int CoordinatorID{ get; set; }
    }
```

My problem is that entity Framework is searching for a column called Manager_UserID (a kind of foreign key to the User table). but this column does not exist on my database. Is there any way to correctly map the database with the models without changing the database structure

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your primary key name to just Id  in each table. EF knows this means make it the primary key

[Update]

Since you mention 3 tables, I think you need Table per Type inheritance TPT as described 
[here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)
You need to mention the User as a navigation property in your Manager class. Also don't inherit from the user.

```
public partial class Manager  
{
    public int ManagerID{ get; set; }
    public virtual User Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Also, only navigational properties need to be virtual. Not field properties like FirstName, LastName

Also look at how your context is set up. There should be 3 DBSets one for each table

Comment: Actually there is no problems with the primary keys EF is searching for a foreign key in the manager table to the User table. the displayed message is : **Invalid column name 'Manager_UserID'**. But in my case the foreign key and the primary key are the same.